# What is sankalpa seva listed in many temples' seva list?

Tags: rituals, temple

Many temples have listed sankalpa seva in their seva list. Please explain what is this.

Comment: Can u give an example of such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Sankalpa** means resolution (an oath to do something)
- **Seva** means service (in this context, service performed to a celestial being)

As per [gururaghavendra1.org](http://www.gururaghavendra1.org/~srsmutt/articles/sankalpa.htm), Sankalpa Seva involves the following steps:

> 1. going to temple at a convenient time
> 2. obtaining darshana
> 3. taking the oath to perform Seva in the prescribed manner
> 4. performing the Seva while following some strict rules